# extract specific rows using pandas

Tags: python

I tried extracting only specific rows greater than or equal to 30 using python.

| Column_A |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 30 |
| 40 |
| 50 |

However, I got an error "

```
'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

" . Please help me to solve this error.

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df[df.Column_A >= 30]

but I got an error "'>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'"

Comment: Probably you need to convert the column to int using `astype(int)` first.

Comment: please verify the column type and if it is not an int or float than convert it into it.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the text column to an integer before comparing:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df[df.Column_A.astype(int) >= 30]
```

That being said, given that you want to treat `Column_A` as a number, perhaps you should convert it to integer.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because `df.Column_A` is a `str` and `30` is an `int`. Pretty sure you can fix this by putting `int()` before `df.Column_A`, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df) df[int(df.Column_A) >= 30]
```